# django: displaying group users count in admin

Tags: django, django-admin, usergroups

I would like to change admin for a group, so it would display how many users are there in a certain group. I'd like to display this in the view showing all groups, the one before you enter admin for certain group. Is it possible? I am talking both about how to change admin for a group and how to add function to `list_display`.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First you'd need to import and subclass `GroupAdmin` from `django.contrib.auth.admin`. In your subclass, define a `user_count` method. Then, unregister the existing Group model from the admin, and re-register the new one.

```
from django.contrib.auth.admin import GroupAdmin
from django.contrib.auth.models import Group

class GroupAdminWithCount(GroupAdmin):
    def user_count(self, obj):
        return obj.user_set.count()

    list_display = GroupAdmin.list_display + ('user_count',)

admin.site.unregister(Group)
admin.site.register(Group, GroupAdminWithCount)
```

Comment: Funny, I already have my own GroupAdmin, just forgot, that I was doing something on that (easier user addition, since you can't add users from default group admin). It was so long time ago, that I simply forgot about that.. Thanks a lot for your help :-)

Comment: Ok, a field appears, but it is always None and user_count function is not called. Any idea, why is this happening?

Comment: Ohk, it should be obj.user_set.count(), rather than self.user_set.count(). Now it works :-)

Comment: Why not defining the function in the model directly ?

Comment: @Glide if it's something you're going to use outside the admin, then sure. But if it's only for use in the admin's list_display, it belongs in the admin class.